# What words for describing or referring to a person showing off wits?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What words (adj., noun) describe or refer to a person who likes to show off their wits/cleverness/smartness by speaking (puns, jokes, sarcasm, satire, etc) or facial/body.language (e.g. smug)?

Comment: **Wit** (note the singular) isn't necessarily the same as sarcasm. _Sarcastic, satirical_ are obvious choices for the latter.

Comment: @Kate The context would seem to imply that the question is about wits (inventive intelligence), not wit (ability to use intelligence for humorous purposes).

Answer (score 4):

In the spirit of "keep it simple", a person who shows of their wit is said to by **witty**.

A thesaurus can give other terms:  humorous
amusing,
droll,
funny,
comic,
chucklesome,
sparkling,
scintillating,
lively,
entertaining,
quick-witted,
sharp-witted,
piquant,
ingenious,
jocular,
waggish

And you can form nouns from some of these, again with the help of a thesaus:
joker,
comic,
wit,
comedian,
clown,
card (informal),
kidder (informal),
jester,
dag (New Zealand, informal),
prankster,
buffoon,
trickster,
humorist,
joculator or (fem.) joculatrix

You can use a dictionary to investigate the particular meaning of these words (and if they are common, casual, rare or dated)

Comment: These are all words that describe _wit_ (humour), rather than _wits_ (intelligence). The fact that the question says “wits/cleverness/smartness”, I think the asker is looking for people who show off their _intelligence_, not their wittiness.

Comment: "by speaking (puns, jokes, sarcasm, satire, etc"  So it means people that show cleverness by humour.   But look more carefully  "ingenious" or "sharp-witted" don't mean  "funny"  I've deliberately left these lists uncurated - it is up to the OP to use a dictionary to find the words that fit their needs, and to see how a thesaurus can be used (teach a person to fish...)

Comment: I just think they’re all in the wrong semantic sphere. The example of a similar word given in the question is _smug_, which seems much more in line with the tone of the question. I would certainly not refer to someone who shows off how clever they are by being sarcastic as ‘sparkling’, ‘scintillating’, ‘entertaining’ or really any of the other words you’ve listed (except perhaps _sharp-witted_) – I might call them smug, supercilious, a smart-alec, etc., but never any of the words you’ve suggested.

Comment: Feel free to write an answer!